# Node.js/ Mongoose TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been plagued with the following error for some time now:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of undefined
    at model.Object.defineProperty.set [as size] (/Users/sourabhdesai/Documents/nodejstuts/expressTest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1200:58)
    at Function.compile (/Users/sourabhdesai/Documents/nodejstuts/expressTest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2516:24)
    at Mongoose.model (/Users/sourabhdesai/Documents/nodejstuts/expressTest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:358:17)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.model (/Users/sourabhdesai/Documents/nodejstuts/expressTest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:600:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sourabhdesai/Documents/nodejstuts/expressTest/user/index.js:87:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

The line where this is thrown *(user/index.js:87)* is:

`MusicQueueObj = db.model('MusicQueue', MusicQueueSchema);`

I have defined `db` before that in the following code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'musicqueuedb');
```

Any clues on what is causing this error? I have searched SO and the internet pretty thoroughly for suggestions but came up with nothing. Im in the process of learning node.js and mongoose so any information can only be beneficial at this point. Im pretty sure I have my schemas set up right.

Here is how I defined the `MusicQueueSchema`:

```
var MusicQueueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    size : Number,
    marker : Number,
    array : [String]
});
```

Here are some of the instance methods:

```
MusicQueueSchema.methods.doubleArray = function() {
    var newArray = new Array( 2 * this.array.length );
    for (var i = this.array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newArray[i] = this.array[i];
    };
    this.array = newArray;
};

MusicQueueSchema.methods.addSong = function(songLink) {
        songLink = songLink.replace("%2F","/");
        if( this.size == this.array.length ) this.doubleArray();
        this.array[this.size] = obj;
        this.size++;
};
MusicQueueSchema.methods.shuffle = function() {
        var permArray = randperm(elems.length); // randperm(...) is a function I defined later on in this module. Its not a method of MusicQueueSchema
        var newArray = new Array(permArray.length);
        for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            newArray[i] = this.array[permArray[i]];
        }
};
```

Those aren't all of them (That would be quite a bit of code), but its enough to show how I wrote all my instance methods for this `MusicQueueSchema`.

Comment: You'll need to show more of the schema definition code.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I just did. Thanks!

Comment: OK - I just tried the basic schema and it works fine. Is there more to it that you're not showing?

Comment: @WiredPrairie You know I just found the problem. When I commented out my code for the size method it worked. I have no idea why, its a pretty straightforward method (And pretty unnecessary so Im okay with removing it). 
This is all it was:
    `MusicQueueSchema.methods.size = function() {
        return this.size;
    };`

Comment: Ooh, okay I figured out why. Ill post an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the cause of this bug. I started to selectively comment pieces of my code to see what was causing the error. Turns out that my `size()` instance method was the problem. This is because it had the same name as my `size` property within the schema. When I changed the name of my `size()` method to `getSize()` the error went away and it worked fine.

**Moral of the Story:** Make sure you don't use the same name twice when defining your mongoose schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Try `MusicQueueObj = mongoose.model("MusicQueue", MusicQueueSchema);`

Comment: it's perfectly legal to define a model on a db connection: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-model

Comment: I did it using `mongoose.model(...)` as well but I was getting the same error with it.